# How to ensure that users can only access/update data created by them

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-queryset

I wish to create an API that allows a user to access/update details of Books only uploaded by them. The user should not have permission to access/update a book that has been created by someone else.

This is my `models.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Project(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Book(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    total_pages = models.IntegerField()
```

This is my `serializers.py`:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = "__all__"
```

Here is my `views.py`:

```
class BookDetails(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
```

How do I modify the `views.py` such that the user can only access/update books created by him?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `get_queryset` method in your view and filter the queryset based on the authenticated user:

```
class BookDetails(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = BookSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Book.objects.filter(project__user=user)
```

Comment: Well this ensures that the user cannot access another user's books but does it also ensure that a user cannot edit another user's book?

Comment: Yes, your view calls the `get_object` method for finding the book that is requsted by user when editing, deleting or retrieving. and `get_object` search for the instane amoung the qureyset returned by the `get_queyset` method.